# onDraw not firing when created

Tags: android

My custom view's onDraw() is not being fired.  Why?  I am using 2.3.3.  Shouldn't the view automatically draw when it gets created?  The onMeasure() method is being fired and I get the correct screen width and height.

```
package com.example.assignment2b;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class AcesActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "DEBUG";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        HeartView heartView = new HeartView(this);
        setContentView(heartView);
        heartView.invalidate();
    }


    class HeartView extends View {

        private int screenWidth;
        private int screenHeight;
        private Context context;

        public HeartView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            this.context = context;

        }

        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)  {
            Log.println(Log.DEBUG, TAG, "onDraw fired"); 
            int cardWidth = screenWidth - 10;
            int cardHeight = (int) (cardWidth * 1.4);


            canvas.drawColor(Color.DKGRAY);

            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            canvas.drawRect(5, (screenHeight/2) - (cardHeight/2), screenWidth - 5, (screenHeight/2) + (cardHeight/2), paint);
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            canvas.drawRect(5, (screenHeight/2) - (cardHeight/2), screenWidth - 5, (screenHeight/2) + (cardHeight/2), paint);

        }

        @Override
        public void onMeasure(int width, int height) {
            Log.println(Log.DEBUG, TAG, "onMeasure fired"); 
            WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay(); 
            screenWidth = display.getWidth();
            screenHeight = display.getHeight();
            setMeasuredDimension(screenWidth, screenHeight);
            Log.println(Log.DEBUG, TAG, "screenWidth = " + screenWidth); 
            Log.println(Log.DEBUG, TAG, "scrrenHeight = " + screenHeight); 
            super.onMeasure(screenWidth, screenHeight);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I noticed 2 things when going through the Android examples:  1) They wrapped the custom View in a layout before sending it off to the Activity and 2) They did not call invalidate() in onCreate.  I'm not sure either of those things will solve your problem, but you might as well give them a shot.

Answer (score 1):

A few different issues going on. First as @dragonwrenn suggested, without a ViewGroup and layout params, your view has no intrinsic bounds. The call to `invalidate()` is unnecessary, but not problematic.

```
public class AcesActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "DEBUG";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new 
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        setContentView(rl);

        HeartView heartView = new HeartView(this);
        heartView.setLayoutParams(params);
        rl.addView(heartView);    
    }

    class HeartView extends View {

        private int screenWidth;
        private int screenHeight;
        private Context context;

         // Moved a couple of variable declarations out of the onDraw method
        Paint paint;
        int cardWidth;
        int cardHeight;

        public HeartView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            this.context = context;
            paint = new Paint();

        }
```

Second, your math for the rects drew them beyond the borders of the screen. I put in some hard numbers just as a test. You will want to rework your numbers to get what you really want. Also, your stroke had no width, so note

```
        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)  {

            Log.println(Log.DEBUG, TAG, "onDraw fired"); 

            canvas.drawColor(Color.DKGRAY);

            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            canvas.drawRect(10, 10, 50, 50, paint);
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
            canvas.drawRect(10, 10, 50, 50, paint);

        }
```

Third, I'm not sure what everything in onMeasure was trying to achieve, but it was causing issues for the view. You shouldn't need more than what's below:

```
        @Override
        public void onMeasure(int width, int height) {
            Log.println(Log.DEBUG, TAG, "onMeasure fired"); 
            screenWidth = width;
            screenHeight = height;

            Log.println(Log.DEBUG, TAG, "screenWidth = " + screenWidth); 
            Log.println(Log.DEBUG, TAG, "scrrenHeight = " + screenHeight); 
            super.onMeasure(screenWidth, screenHeight);
            cardWidth = screenWidth - 10;
            cardHeight = (int) (cardWidth * 1.4);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Edit: note to original poster, the above is functional code tested in Eclipse. If each section is copied and pasted exactly, it will work.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.  Unfortunately, after I implemented them, onDraw still does not fire.

Comment: If you copy this code exactly, it will fire. I ran it in Eclipse myself, saw a square on the screen and the onDraw in logcat. Try it again.

Answer (score 0):

Do the below changes in your `onMeasure()` method: 
Declare the display metrics in your class.
`private DisplayMetrics m_metrics;`

> ```
>      @Override
>     public void onMeasure(int width, int height) {
>         Log.println(Log.DEBUG, TAG, "onMeasure fired"); 
>             Display m_display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
>         m_metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
>         m_display.getMetrics(m_metrics);
>         screenWidth = m_display.getWidth();
>         screenHeight = m_display.getHeight();
>             super.onMeasure(screenWidth, screenHeight);
>     }
> ```

Comment: Thank you for the tip.  Unfortunately, it does not cause onDraw to fire when I tried it.

Comment: I have tried it and also tested it . I got it work successfully and also in my logcat it prints the onDraw fired message. Please try out by copying my code.